# How can I access a list of character controllers variables in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so I'm currently trying to set my enemies `isAggressivebool` to `true` if another enemy takes damage.

```cs
//list for enemies
public List<CharacterController> enemies = new List<CharacterController>();

//variables for aggro range and aggressive check
public float aggroRange;
public bool isAggressive;

int nearestTarget = 0;
//cycling through player character list
for ( int i = 1; i < GameManager.instance.playerCharacters.Count; i++ )
{
    //if any of the player characters positions arent within our aggro range
    if ( Vector3.Distance ( transform.position, GameManager.instance.playerCharacters [ nearestTarget ].transform.position ) > aggroRange )
    {
        //they are not aggressive
        isAggressive = false;
        // if non aggressive enemies health becomes lower than max health, they have taken damage
        if ( GameManager.instance.activePlayer.currentHealth < GameManager.instance.activePlayer.maxHealth )
        {

            //||||  Figure out how to cylce through enemies and set them all to aggressive when one takes damage ||||
            foreach ( CharacterController allies in enemies )
            {
                //solution 1 - setting larget aggro range so they aggro anyway
                //aggroRange = 20f;
                //isAggressive = true;
                //solution 2 - accessing the component on the script?
                //allies.GetComponent<AIBrain>().aggroRange = 20f;
                //allies.GetComponent<AIBrain>().isAggressive = true;
            }
            //set them as aggressive - Disables when fixed above logic
            isAggressive = true;

        }
    }
    //players are within AI aggro range
    else
    {
        //set them as aggressive
        isAggressive = true;

    }
}
```

The enemies are being added to the list correctly and trying to cycle through the list in second `foreach` loop and set them aggressive. Unsuccessful attempts are added as comments.

Comment: What was the issue with using `GetComponent`?

Comment: It's not updating each character in the lists bool / range variable. It just does nothing.

Comment: what exactly is your loop for? You are not using `i` anywhere ...

Answer (score 1):

Using events is generally a more efficient and organised way to handle this type of situation

One way to achieve this is to add an event to your `AIBrain` script that will be triggered whenever that character takes damage. Then, you can subscribe to that event, and when the event is triggered, set the `isAggressive` boolean to `true` for all subscribed characters.

In your `AIBrain` script, define an event for taking damage:

```cs
public event Action<AIBrain> OnTakeDamage;

public void TakeDamage()
{
    // take damage logic...
    
    // trigger the OnTakeDamage event
    OnTakeDamage?.Invoke(this);
}
```

You'll need to call `TakeDamage()` when the enemy gets damaged (so wherever you would take damage, also call this). In your `AIBrain` script, subscribe to the `OnTakeDamage` event for each enemy in the enemies list:

```cs
void Start ( )
{
    // subscribe to OnTakeDamage event for each enemy in the enemies list
    foreach ( AIBrain enemy in enemies )
    {
        enemy.OnTakeDamage += OnEnemyTakeDamage;
    }
}

void OnDestroy ( )
{
    // unsubscribe from OnTakeDamage event for each enemy in the enemies list
    foreach ( AIBrain enemy in enemies )
    {
        enemy.OnTakeDamage -= OnEnemyTakeDamage;
    }
}

void OnEnemyTakeDamage ( AIBrain enemy )
{
    // set isAggressive to true for all enemies
    foreach ( AIBrain ally in enemies )
    {
        ally.isAggressive = true;
    }
}
```

With this implementation, whenever an enemy takes damage and triggers the `OnTakeDamage` event, the `OnEnemyTakeDamage` method will be called for all subscribed enemies, setting their `isAggressive` boolean to `true`.

Let me know if this works, or if you need help with anything!

Comment: Hi Cody. Thanks for your reply. I need to look into events. Something I'm unfamiliar with in my few months learning C# and unity I'm sure there's many great applications for it.

I stepped away from the computer after troubleshooting for a few hours and posting this thread and came back and solved it funnily enough. 

the isAggressive = false above the foreach was preventing the if statement from actually setting the variables utilising allies.GetComponent<AIBrain>() lines. Moving it set that after the foreach loop seems to fix the issue.

Comment: I ill look into your method using events in more detail because i'm going to create pods enemies so will need to prevent triggering every enemy and i think that could be better.

Answer (score 0):

```
        for (int i = 1; i < GameManager.instance.playerCharacters.Count; i++)
    {
        //if any of the player characters positions arent within our aggro range
        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, GameManager.instance.playerCharacters[nearestTarget].transform.position) > aggroRange)
        {
            //they are not aggressive
            //isAggressive = false;
            // if non aggressive enemies health becomes lower than max health, they have taken damage
            if (GameManager.instance.activePlayer.currentHealth < GameManager.instance.activePlayer.maxHealth)
            {
                
                //||||  Figure out how to cylce through enemies and set them all to aggressive when one takes damage ||||
                foreach (CharacterController allies in enemies)
                {
                     
                    //solution 1 - setting larget aggro range so they aggro anyway
                    //aggroRange = 20f;
                    //isAggressive = true;
                    //solution 2 - accessing the component on the script?
                    allies.GetComponent<AIBrain>().aggroRange = 20f;
                    allies.GetComponent<AIBrain>().isAggressive = true;


                }
                //set them as aggressive - Disables when fixed above logic
                //isAggressive = true;
             
                isAggressive = false;

            }
```

Moving isAggressive to after the loop fixed the issue. Unsure why.